# Querying Dynamics 365 for specific data based on filter and getting JToken back

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, dynamics-365

I'm debugging a Get request to the string path of

`$"{orgname}.api.crm.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.1/accounts?$select=name,accountnumber,accountid&$filter=contains(accountnumber,%27(ellaId)%27)"`

It's sending back null values although I know the value of the filter for this specific query (`ellaId's` value) is correct and in D365. Is the query wrong? I must be missing something obvious from the Microsoft documentation. I've tried replacing %27 with the actual ' instead, but to no avail (if that would even work.)

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right syntax would be

```
$"{orgname}.api.crm.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.1/accounts?$select=name,accountnumber,accountid&$filter=contains(accountnumber,'{ellaId}')"
```

assuming you store the value of your search term inside a variable called `ellaId`.

However if you use C# I suggest to use the official SDK (you don't need to deal with authentication timeouts by yourself), but if you want you can still use the Web API endpoint. If you need a tool to generate such requests you can use the one I created: [Dataverse REST Builder](https://github.com/GuidoPreite/DRB).

It does not generate the C# code but at least you can see the generated endpoint url.

The site has also a Demo available if you want to test it before installing it.

Comment: I must have read the documentation wrong because I could have sworn there were parentheses around the value itself (ellaId in this case) but your query worked. Thank you very much!